# plato, spinoza, leibnitz and aristotle

Tags: history-of-philosophy

I find this sentence without any elaboration-

- ***Spinoza’s philosophy was static as that of Plato while Leibnitz’s
  system was dynamic as that of Aristotle***"

What does it mean ?

Thank You.

Comment: What is the source for the quote?

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost: Such oversimplified characterisations possibly do more harm than good for philosophical understanding. They may be appropriate for politicised slogans, or perhaps, a post-it note as a reminder of a study to be (much!) expanded later, but not for disciplined inquiry, and this is not pointless pedantry.

Having emphasised the potential risk of being misled, I think the statement might be given sense in a way:

On the one side, Plato’s theory of forms and Spinoza’s theory of substance and attributes envisage an eternal totality as the source of reality and truth. On the other side, their critics, Aristotle and Leibniz view, while adopting or admitting many ideas of theirs, the particular things as the ground of reality and truth. Hence, while the former give priority to an unchanging totality, the latter allows room to spawn particulars, or individuals.

Certainly, this is only to hint at a possible reading of the statement; the metaphysical views of these philosophers defy any tabular presentations. Each one of them has given rise to a specific field of scholarship and even a cursory sketch of an explanation of the parallelism mentioned cannot be offered within the limits of a question. So, I would refer you to the excellent introductory books on them to further the pursuit of the topic.